# $<$ in a preorder

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, relations

The author of the book I am studying defines $<$ for a poset as

> If $x, y \in X$, where $X$ is a poset, then we shall write $x < y$ to mean that $x \le y$ and $x \ne y$.

From this, I can conceive of two definitions for $<$ for a preorder:

> 1) If $x, y \in X$, where $X$ is a **preorder**, then we shall write $x < y$ to mean that $x \le y$ and $x \ne y$.

or

> 2) If $x, y \in X$, where $X$ is a **preorder**, then we shall write $x < y$ to mean that $x \le y$ and $y \not\le x$.

Which of these is more appropriate?

Comment: The second one. As it may happen that $x \leq y $, $y\leq x$ and $x\ne y$.

Comment: This is discussed on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preorder#Constructions)

Comment: @azarel That is one reason for this and [a related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170081/equal-elements-vs-isomorphic-elements-in-a-preoder) question.

Comment: @Henry Thanks for the link. I'll study that in more detail as I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may know by now that if you have a preorder then you can take a quotient by the equivalent relation $x\sim y\iff x\leq y\land y\leq x$ and have a poset.

The definition should be such that it carries over to the quotient, so the second definition is more appropriate. In the first one we can have $x\neq y$ and $x\leq y\land y\leq x$, but $x\sim y$ so in the induced poset $[x]=[y]$.

Answer (score 3):

(1) is incorrect, since if $\leq$ is only a pre-order, then it can have $x\leq y\leq x$ with $x\neq y$, and this will mean that the relation $\lt$ defined in (1) is not transitive, since you will have $x\lt y\lt x$, but $x\not\lt x$. So in (1), you won't have a partial order.

(2) is the strict partial order commonly associated with a pre-order; it is transitive and irreflexive.