# $<$ on a preorder is a strict partial order

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, relations

**Definition:** Suppose $X$ is a preorder. Define $x < y$ as $x \le y$ and $y \not\le x$ for each $x, y \in X$.

**Question:** Show that this gives a strict partial order on $X$.

Comment: This is related to [an earlier question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170517/in-a-preorder). I decided to post a new question in order to aggregate everything I have learned in one place without detracting from the answerers earlier contributions.

Comment: Should that be $x<y$ if $x\leq y$ and $y\nleq x$ ?

Comment: @EricStucky Good catch. I fixed it.

Comment: You should probably slow down on them retags. I'm also not sure that we need *two* tags for [preorders] and [partial-orders], in fact I'm not 100% certain that either is particularly useful either. Please bring this up to a meta thread *before* continuing the retagging journey.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I finished the 5 or 6 retags already. I apologize for not discussing it in meta first. I was not aware that was part of the protocol here. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We must show that the relation $<$ is irreflexive and transitive.

**Irreflexive:** Suppose $x \in X$. Then $x \le x$, so $x \not< x$.

**Transitive:** Suppose $x, y, z \in X$ such that $x < y$ and $y < z$. Then $x \le y$, $y \not\le x$, $y \le z$, and $z \not\le y$. By the transitivity of $\le$, we immediately have $x \le z$. Now assume that $z \le x$. Then $z \le y$. This is a contradition.